# How can I open a Provider Hosted App in SP Modal Dialog in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, office-365-developer, microsoft

I need to open a provider hosted app inside a SharePoint Modal Dialog. The provider hosted app is hosted in AZURE Web App Services.  I have tried several examples that I could see in Microsoft documentation but it does not work. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff410058(v=office.14)  Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

@Gabriel Bravo,

I created a [get started SharePoint provided host add-in](https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/SharePointAddInprovider/SharePointAddInproviderWeb/Pages/Default.aspx) and deploy it on Azure web service. By means of below js code (through Content Editor web part), I can open the add-in web page in a dialogue.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#savebtn").click(function () {
                var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

                options.url = "https://sharepointaddinproviderweb.azurewebsites.net/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fisvdevchat%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fsites%2Fsbdev&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=8&SPProductNumber=16%2E0%2E20628%2E12006";
                options.width = 600;
                options.height = 400;
                options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);

                SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
            });

        });

        function CloseCallback(result, target) {
            if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
                // Run OK Code
                alert('ok');
            }
            if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
                // Run Cancel Code
                alert('cancel');
            }
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>This is a Button</h1>

    <input id="savebtn" type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" />

</body>

</html>
```

The targeted URL is copied from the location where you click to open the provider add-in.

Test:

[image]

BR